# How to prevent a div from moving when another div next to it expands

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 2 blocks next to each other a large and a smaller one. The smaller one can expand (how much it expands is variable).
When it expand the top of a 3rd div (same width placed under the first block) is moving so the top matches the bottom of the expanding div. What I need is the 3rd block to stay at the bottom of the first block.

I've tried putting block 1 and 3 in one col-md-8, and the 2nd block in a col-md-4. This works BUT on mobile i need the expanding block between the first and third block. I've also tried looking at the card-columns from bootstrap but i can't define the width or change the order of appearance on mobile.

I made a fiddle to show the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/k53rnvpb/1/

```js
$('.expand').click(function() {
  $('.block-2').toggleClass('height-300');
})
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

[class^="col-"] {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.block-1 {
  height: 200px;
}

.block-2 {
  height: 150px;
}

.block-3 {
  height: 200px;
}

.height-300 {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 block-1">
      Block 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 block-2">
      Block 2
      <p>I need to be between block 1 and 3 on mobile</p>
      <button class='btn btn-primary expand'>Expand</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 block-3">
      Block 3
      <p>If block 2 expands i still need to be attached to block 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So i either need to stop the bottom block from moving when the other expands, or i need to find a clean way to have the expanding div in between the other 2 blocks on mobile (when i put the large blocks in a col-md-8 and the expanding in a col-md-4)

I hope the problem is clear and thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try something like this, just tweek it a bit https://jsfiddle.net/spqbrwmc/1/

Comment: Are you OK with grid solutions?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen like i said in the question, if i do that the order on mobile isn't right. On mobile i need the expanding div to be the 2nd block, its now the last.

Comment: if you want your block 1 and 3 to stick together while block 2 is in the middle of both, wouldn't block 2 cover the bottom contents of 1 and top contents of 3?

Comment: @Gosi On mobile it needs to be in the middle, on desktop it has to be next to them. Nothing is overlapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways. One is to use duplicate div content but that would not be effecient. Here is the another solution. By using media query. One thing to note is that you have given border to column and I have used border for content dive.

This solves both problems. 
1. Expanding div will not effect on height
2. Block 2 will remain in middle of block 1 and block 3

```js
$('.expand').click(function() {
  $('.block-2').toggleClass('height-300');

})
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

[class^="col-"] {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.block-1 {
  height: 200px;
  clear: both;
}

.block-2 {
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .block-2 {
    position: relative;
  }
}

.block-3 {
  height: 200px;
}

.height-300 {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 block-1">
      Block 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4" style="padding: 0;">
      <div class=" block-2">
        Block 2
        <p>I need to be between block 1 and 3 on mobile</p>
        <button class='btn btn-primary expand'>Expand</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 block-3">
      Block 3
      <p>If block 2 expands i still need to be attached to block 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g21eqyxn/11/

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Didn't want to duplicate but the position absolute worked like a charm. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I added an additional `<div class="expander">` inside the second expanding DIV and changed the *height expansion* to this inner div. I hope it is working as per you want now.

At the end of the css, there is a media query. fine tune to match perfectly with your small screen resolution.

*It will not work properly in the snippet since bootstrap is not included. Try this in your code.*

```js
$('.expand').click(function(){
 $('.expander').toggleClass('height-300');
})
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

[class^="col-"],
.expander{
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
.block-1{
    height: 200px;
}
.block-2{
    height: 150px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.block-3{
    height:200px;
}
.height-300{
    height: 300px;
}

/*Fine tune this media query based on your desired mobile resolution*/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  .block-2{
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 block-1">
            Block 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 block-2">
          <div class="expander">
          Block 2
            <p>I need to be between block 1 and 3 on mobile</p>
            <button class='btn btn-primary expand'>Expand</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 block-3">
            Block 3
            <p>If block 2 expands i still need to be attached to block 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```